# Any idea why this jquery wouldn't work in IE but works in firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I have some code to make sure these two divs with id's content and txtCotent are the same height.

```
  <script language = "javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var h = $('#wrapContent#').css('height');
    $('#content, #txtContent').css('height', h);
                                });
    </script>
```

Any ideas as to why this wouldn't work in IE? Here is the link ... http://students.uwf.edu/bmg17/workshop/index.cfm

Comment: Bri you actually have 2 divs with the ID of content which can actually wreak havoc in jQuery. You should change the IDs to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var h = $('#wrapContent').height();
    $('#content, #txtContent').css('height', h + 'px');
});
```

EDIT: Changed to `height()` instead of `css('height')`.

Comment: ALWAYS...so trivial ; ; Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I added the + 'px' in doesn't work in firefox now. haha.

Comment: I printed out what was in h and it says 1014px ...so that is before adding in the 'px'. :\ Hmmm.

Comment: @Bri sorry about that. You actually want to use `height()` to get the height of the original div, since `css('height')` will return different things depending on the browser (as you have discovered). `height()` will always just return the integer value, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#content, #txtContent').css('height', h);
```

h should equal `h + 'px'`

You need to express UNITS, in this case, px = pixels.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above because you are using the css() you have to specify a pixel unit for 'height', however, if you use height() instead you can do:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

var h = $('#wrapContent#').height();
$('#content, #txtContent').height(h);
                            });
</script>
```

Without specifying pixels because if no unit is given jQuery will assume pixels. Though can specify a different unit if needed.